# install opencv nonfree features with macports

Tags: opencv, macports

I want to install opencv non free features.
I've tried this:

```
sudo port install opencv +contrib
```

But i cannot see libopencv_nonfree.dylib in /opt/local/lib
(i've also search file on the whole disk)

Is there a way ton install opencv non free features with macports ?

Thanks

Comment: If you already have opencv installed, you need to use `sudo port upgrade --enforce-variants opencv +contrib` to change the active variants. For a list of the files installed by a port, run `port contents $portname`.

Comment: It does not work anymore. I do not have libopencv_nonfree.dylib file on my disk...

Answer (score 0):

If you go through OpenCV libraries in "opt/local/lib", it includes all the libraries contained in non-free module like "xfeatures2D, xphotos and ximageproc.dylib"

Comment: They are not there.